# html table cell width 0 not working?

Tags: html, css

for some reason I have to use a table which contains two cells in each row I want to animate the width of the first cell by setting its overflow property to hidden and its width to 0 but when I set the width to 0 the actual rendered width is 3px
here is my markup

```css
  .news-element {
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  .news-element-table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    display: table;
  }
  .news-element-img {
    width: 17vw;
    height: 300px;
    display: table-cell;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    .news-element-img-wrapper {
      position: absolute;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
    img {
      position: absolute;
      height: 100%;
      width: auto;
      min-width: 100%;
      top: 0;
      left: 50%;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      transform: translateX(-50%);
      margin: auto;
    }
    // h 336 
    // w 236
  }
  .news-element-description {
    width: 0;
    // w 414 
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    .news-element-description-wrapper {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 10px;
    }
  }
  .news-element-title {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    background: #2E3132;
    color: #fff;
  }
```

```html
<div class=" news-wrapper ">

  <div class="news-element ">

    <table class="news-element-table ">
      <tr>
        <td class="news-element-description">
          <div class="news-element-description-wrapper">
            <p>
              blah blah blah
            </p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="news-element-img">
          <div class="news-element-img-wrapper">
            <img src="<?= getFileLink(" /assests/imgs/Media05.jpg "); ?>" />
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <div class="news-element-title">
      <h6>foo </h6>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I'm using the table method so I can set the height of the first cell according to its sibling  .

Comment: did you check cellspacing?

Comment: yes I did border-collapse: collapse

Comment: can you post code so we can take a look

Comment: I tried to delete everything in the cell but it kept taking a space

Comment: This is not valid HTML nor valid CSS

Comment: actually I'm not using table tag in my code instead I'm using display:table and display : table-cell 
but I posted it like that to make compatible width the question

Comment: You can't nest css styles. each style has to be its own section.

Comment: Also html/css comments are `<!-- This is a comment -->`. They are different from javascript comments `// This is not a comment`.

Comment: clearly I'm using scss

Comment: @ramizk remove the auto-added browser padding by adding the asterisk "select-all" css to the TOP of your css : `*{padding:0; margin:0}`   btw, bcr666, css comments are different from html comments..`/* this is a css comment */ `

Answer (score 4):

I used this CSS to completely hide my cells:

```
.hide-col {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0!important;
  max-width: 0!important;
  padding: 0!important;
  border-width: 0!important;
  font-size: 0!important;
}
```

Comment: When combined with "<col width="0">", "font-size" seems to be sufficient to completely hide the column.

Comment: Unless you' re working with IE.

Answer (score -1):

I just had a similar problem with table row heights and column widths that refused to become 0. My solution was to set width and max-width or height and max-height to s.th. slightly *above* 0, like so

```
width:0.01px; max-width:0.01px;
height:0.01px; max-height:0.01px;
```

perhaps combined with

```
visibility:hidden;
```

No idea, why setting them to 0 does not work...